# Disable row in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular 2.I have created a table based on dropdown selection.I am able to generate a new row on button click (cloning the row). How can I disable the previous row. so values will be change in only current new generated row.how can I achieve this any alternative is welcome.thanks in advance. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7P2j.png)

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: 'app/test/test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/test/test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

makes: SelectItem[];
selectedMake: string;

motors: SelectItem[];
selectedMotorType: string;

poles: SelectItem[];
selectedPole: string;

}

constructor() {

  this.makes = [];
     this.makes.push({label:'Select makes', value:null});
     this.makes.push({label:'Siemens', value:{id:1, name: 'Siemens', code: 'Siemens'}});
     this.makes.push({label:'ABS', value:{id:2, name: 'ABS', code: 'ABS'}});

  this.motors = [];
     this.motors.push({label:'Select Motor Type', value:null});
     this.motors.push({label:'IE1', value:{id:11, name: 'IE1', code: 'IE1'}});
     this.motors.push({label:'IE2', value:{id:12, name: 'IE2', code: 'IE2'}});
     this.motors.push({label:'IE3', value:{id:13, name: 'IE3', code: 'IE3'}});

  this.poles = [];
     this.poles.push({label:'Select Pole Type', value:null});
     this.poles.push({label:'2 Pole', value:{id:21, name: '2Pole', code: '2Pole'}});
     this.poles.push({label:'4 Pole', value:{id:22, name: '4Pole', code: '4Pole'}});
     this.poles.push({label:'6 Pole', value:{id:23, name: '6Pole', code: '6Pole'}});
}


//code for button click new row generate
  rows = [{name: ''}];
  name = "new";
  addRow() {
    this.rows.push({name: this.name});
  }
//=================

  private textValue = "initial value";
      private log: string ='result';
      private kw: string = 'kw';
      private frame: number = 0;

DisplayResult(){
  if(this.selectedMake.name=='ABS' && this.selectedMotorType.name=='IE1' ){
    alert(this.selectedMake.name);
    this.log = 'IABVC5Z' '\n'
    this.kw = 'new' '\n'
  }}
```

```html
<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p class="col-sm-3" >Makes :</p>
    <p-dropdown class="col-sm-4" [options]="makes" [(ngModel)]="selectedMake" [style]="{'width':'200px'}" ></p-dropdown>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p class="col-sm-3" >Motor Type :</p>
    <p-dropdown class="col-sm-4" [options]="motors" [(ngModel)]="selectedMotorType" [style]="{'width':'200px'}" ></p-dropdown>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p class="col-sm-3" >Pole Type :</p>
    <p-dropdown class="col-sm-4" [options]="poles" [(ngModel)]="selectedPole" [style]="{'width':'200px'}" ></p-dropdown>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <button class="" pButton type="button" class="ui-button-danger" (click)="addRow()" label = " Add New Motor"></button>
  <button class="" pButton type="button" (click)="DisplayResult()" label="Display Result"></button>

</div>



<table id="t01">
<tr>
<th>S.No.</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Type Refrence</th>
<th>KW Rating</th>
<th>Frame Size</th>
<th>Voltage</th>
<th>Frequency</th>
<th>Features</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor=" let row of rows">
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="qty" name="qty"></td>
<td>{{log}}</td>
<td>{{kw}}</td>
<td>{{frame}}</td>
<td>415 v</td>
<td>50 Hz</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm having a bit trouble understanding the problem here, could you perhaps try and explain a bit more?

Comment: @ajt_82 this question have different approch that i was trying to solve. all I wanted to add a new row to the table (on click of add new motor button, for reference you can see the screenshot in question). I am able to generated a new row with index. I need help for how can i push the data in new generated row (on click of show result, show result button was able to display the data for first row) previous rows should be unchanged.everytime when i click for new motor, data show be display in new row. ts code https://pastebin.com/zCL6qYRs , html code https://pastebin.com/Ywv3KJxP

Comment: I think I get your issue now. You should create objects from the "form" (you could actually make it a form) and push those objects to array. Objects would for example have property `log`, so then in this case all `log` are unique. Now you are just using one property `log`, which means that all fields in the table will have the same value.

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks, i got your point , but is there any way in angular 2 to push values in a row with particular index. without changing previous rows. I mean without using the object, can we only update the rows with these same values. P.S I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the disabled property in the tag as shown

```
[disabled]="!available"
```

or with the full tag

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!available">Submit</button>
```

On the click event you can then either make the variable true or not to toggle it